# ionic, pass scope variable to popover scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to pass a variable from the view scope ($scope.sort`) into the popover scope.
Once set in the popover, the variable 'goes out' of it with no issue though, with code below in`$scope.closeSortPopover`.

I thought the popover scope was the same as the scope of the controller it comes from.
But it seems it's not the case.
Where is the popover scope ?
If I understand correctly from [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicPopover/) the popover scope is a child of the controller scope. So how can I access it... ?

FYI my popover is a list of `<ion-radio>`s offering different sorting opions for the big list in my main view.

html:

```
<button ng-click="openSortPopover($event, sort)">
```

controllers.js

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/computeSortPopover.html', {
   scope: $scope
}).then(function(popover) {
   $scope.sortPopover = popover;
});
$scope.openSortPopover = function($event, sort) {
   $scope.sortPopover.show($event);
};
$scope.closeSortPopover = function(sort) {
   $scope.sortPopover.hide();
   $scope.sort = sort;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller js, you are assigning the scope of the controller to the scope of the popover. Thus all the methods in the controller scope are accessible via the popover view. In other words, both the controller view and popover view share the same scope.

In fact you might think this a violation of mvc as one controller cannot own two views, but with angular, you actually can't otherwise.

To create isolated scope, your only option is directives.

Comment: thanks but it was not working if the sort variable was not in an object

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that due to javascript inheritence, the scope variable must be contained into an object to be passed to inherited scopes.

So instead of this:

```
$scope.sort = ....
```

I declared this in my controller:

```
$scope.data={};
$scope.data.sort = ....
```

and used in my html (both in the initial view and in the popover templates):

```
data.sort
```

Documented here apparently: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance